# Hibernate 4.2 left join fetch migration issue

Tags: hibernate, hql, left-join, fetch

I am currently migrating from hibernate 3 to 4. I managed to sort out the dependencies but I am facing the popular: `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list...` issue . I used to do the following in order to force Hibernate to fetch the entire object and it's collection properties i.e. an Employee with many Departments and the address of each department.

So in HQL I had something like:

```
select e from Employee as e left join fetch e.department left join fetch e.department.address where e.id= ....
```

This worked fine but in the new version of Hibernate I can only fetch the properties that belong directly to the employee object and not the department. What I would like is to get all the properties because the session is closed after the query and lazy fetching obviously raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was needed and I am posting here for others having the same issue.

The query should be:

```
select e from Employee as e left join fetch e.department as department left join fetch department.address where e.id=...
```

We have to use an alias `department`.